# Magpie RSS / User Authorization

Tags: php, rss

How can I get Magpie RSS to identify itself as a user?

HTTP Response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

is the error that i'm getting returned

Comment: You are going to need send User/Pass parameters along with the request.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't post any code, I assume you're calling MagpieRSS like:

```
$rss = fetch_rss('http://www.site.com/feed.rss');
```

To identify as user/password, just change the URL to this format:

```
$rss = fetch_rss('http://username:password@www.site.com/feed.rss');
```

See [PHP's `parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) for more info.